Change default search order from Visual studio properties to avoid DLL preloading attacks
I'm working on an application(C++ language) that makes use of certain Windows libraries. For instance, I can find the version of any application using Version.lib. I've added the library to Visual Studio's linker settings. I am unable to provide the library's precise location since it is a Windows library.
The library's default search order is as follows:

The directory from which the application loaded

The current working directory (CWD)

The system directory

The 16-bit system directory

The Windows directory

The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable


Due to the fact that my application is being utilized from the user directory, DLL preloading attacks could occur where the hacker can place a custom Version.dll in the same directory from which my application is loaded. This custom version.dll will be loaded since the application loads all the dll initially. How can this problem be overcomed?
I even tried to mention the path of Version.lib in linker additional dependency, still it first searches in current directory. I used Process monitor to find out that dll is searched first in current directory.

It is even more complicated when you use manifests (which can control what dll's you actually load too). Also know a .lib file is statically linked so you probably mean .dll.  In general if you want to know what dll you use, copy it into the folder of your application. But in the end there is not much you can do to avoid "attacks", dll injection (at runtime) is also a thing. So what is it you are really worried about?

Perhaps the SetDllDirectory call will serve.

You might wish to consider the SetSearchPathMode() function which, for the current process, can be used to force looking in system directories before user directories.

Before using SetSearchPathMode, application searches and tries to load the dll which will lead to attacks. That's why I am searching for any a property in linker settings.

Add a manifest to your program, see Isolated Applications and Side-by-side Assemblies

The major purpose of isolated applications and side-by-side assemblies is to resolve version conflicts. Though it addressess my issue, the hardcoded nature of the version necessitates regular revisions. Is it possible to do this without mentioning the version?

Does your DLL support delayed loading? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import?view=msvc-170

Yes my application supports Delay DLL loading. I added Version.dll in delay Loaded DLLs and then used the SetSearchPathMode(BASE_SEARCH_PATH_ENABLE_SAFE_SEARCHMODE) ,SetDllDirectoryA("") at the startup of the application. Even though the safe search mode is enabled, the DLL's are searched from current directory. Not sure why SetSearchPathMode doesn't reflect for the linker properties. In this case, if I load the DLLs using LoadLibraryEx explicitly after enabling safe search mode, it satisfies my needs.

Glad to know delay loading meets what you need! I converted my comment to an answer.

"The library's default search order is as follows" - I'm curious about this. SafeDllSearchMode puts the current directory way down the list, after the system directory where version.dll lives. It has been enabled by default since XP SP2 and 2k SP4, i.e. for many, many years now. It takes a registry hack to disable it. Why is this actually a problem for your use case?

If dll supports delay loading,
/DELAYLOAD (Delay Load Import)

The /DELAYLOAD option causes the DLL that's specified by dllname to be
loaded only on the first call by the program to a function in that
DLL.

And use LoadLibrary to load the DLL of the specified path.

To remove the current directory from the library search path, you can create a tiny wrapper executable which has no dependencies on anything except kernel32.dll (which is a known system DLL and is loaded from a fixed location), call SetDllDirectory with the application's own directory, and then launch the actual application and exit. SetDllDirectory's modified search path is inherited by child processes. (Also, despite the scary sounding "effectively disables safe DLL search mode" in the docs, it actually makes the process safer by removing the current directory completely.)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya
